# What characters need to be escaped to turn this into a string?

Tags: javascript

I have some javascript that I want to "stringify" but when I do, I get the error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ?`

My question is how to I change it so that I can pass it as a string? I think I have to "escape" certain characters - is that just as simple as adding \ before them?

The original code in the .js file looks like this:

```
c = function(e) {
            return /^\s*(?:text\/\S*|application\/xml|\S*\/\S*\+xml)\s*;.*charset\s*=\s*utf-8/i.test(e.type) ? new Blob([String.fromCharCode(65279), e], {
                type: e.type
            }) : e
        }
```

I want to create a string of the javascript, so I can place it into a page programmatically - so I started with this:

```
str+="          c = function(e) {";
str+="               return /^\s*(?:text\/\S*|application\/xml|\S*\/\S*\+xml)\s*;.*charset\s*=\s*utf-8/i.test(e.type) ? new Blob([String.fromCharCode(65279), e], {";
str+="                    type: e.type";
str+="               }) : e";
str+="            },";
```

But when the javascript is placed onto the page using the DOM, that's when I get the error message.

Thanks for any help,

Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think here is your problem

```
return /^\s*(?:text\/\S*|application\/xml|\S*\/\S*\+xml)\s*;
```

that ; is creating confusion